# In play framework 2.5 is there a way to turn on logging for all actors?

Tags: akka, playframework-2.5

I'm learning Play Framework async programming using Akka actors.

It all seems really cool and stuff.  But in the docs, it seems to suggest if I want logging for an actor I need to add a line in the logback.XML file for each actor..

`private final LoggingAdapter log = Logging.getLogger(context().system(), this);`

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SettingsLogger

`<!-- Set logging for all Akka library classes to INFO -->
<logger name="akka" level="INFO" />
<!-- Set a specific actor to DEBUG -->
<logger name="actors.MyActor" level="DEBUG" />`

seriously?  A line for every actor?  There must be a way to globally set logging for all actors.  Does anyone know a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What kind of logging? lifecycle events?

Comment: My own debug statements  Not interested in framework events.